# How to take Columns with values by Column names?

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to take some columns from datatable then copy to another data table.
Is this possible?
For example; I want to take ID and Name column and their row values.

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("ID");
        table.Columns.Add("Name");
        table.Columns.Add("Surname");
        table.Rows.Add("1", "Mike","Zt");
        table.Rows.Add("2", "Richard", "Milko");
        table.Rows.Add("3", "Sumo", "Sansimo");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a really simple way to do what you ask

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("ID");
table.Columns.Add("Name");
table.Columns.Add("Surname");
table.Rows.Add("1", "Mike","Zt");
table.Rows.Add("2", "Richard", "Milko");
table.Rows.Add("3", "Sumo", "Sansimo");

DataTable newTable = table.DefaultView.ToTable(false, new string[] {"ID", "Name"});
foreach(DataRow r in newTable.Rows)
        Console.WriteLine("ID=" + r.Field<string>("ID") + ", Name=" + r.Field<string>("Name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1:**

Copy the columns (ID,Name) and their rows data from one DataTable (table) to another DataTable (table2).

```
// create new table to which you want copy the first table
DataTable table2 = new DataTable();

// now copy the columns (ID,Name) from table to table2
foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
{
    if(column.ColumnName == "ID" || column.ColumnName == "Name")
        table2.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName);
}

// copy the all data of columns (ID,Name) from table to table2
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    // initialize the new row for your data
    List<string> rowData = new List<string>();

    // add your columns (ID,Name) data to the new row
    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {
        if(column.ColumnName == "ID" || column.ColumnName == "Name")
            rowData.Add(row[column.ColumnName].ToString());
    }

    // add the data row to the new DataTable (table2)
    table2.Rows.Add(rowData);
}
```